# Two double sums must be equal, struggle with indices

Tags: summation

Empirically, these $2$ sums are supposed to be equal:

> $$\sum_{k=0}^n \sum_{j=0}^k a_j b_{k-j} = \sum_{k=0}^n  a_k \sum_{j=0}^{n-k} b_j$$

I failed to prove it with a "change of index" and now I am thinking the only possible way to solve this is to use $\sum _{i+j \leq n}$ which has always been a true nightmare for me.

Here is my unfruitful work:
$$ \sum_{k=0}^n \sum_{j=0}^k a_j b_{k-j} = \sum_{k=0}^n \sum_{j=k}^0 a_{k-j} b_j$$

Comment: Shouldn't it suffice to use the change of index $j' := k - j$?

Comment: @BrunoB it requires an additional step as the first sum has $a_j$ and the second $a_k$

Comment: @BrunoB Probably not. The sum really is $\sum_{0\le i,j, i+j\le n}a_ib_j$ and the first double sum adds the "diagonals" while the second one adds the "horizontals". The OP may be right that they should switch to a single sum.

Comment: Thanks for indicating my errors, I should have been more careful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\begin{array}{cll}&\sum_{k=0}^{n}\sum_{j=0}^ka_jb_{k-j}\\=&\sum_{j=0}^{n}\sum_{k=j}^na_jb_{k-j}&\text{Swap sums, }j\le k\iff k\ge j\\=&\sum_{j=0}^{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-j}a_jb_k&\text{Substitution }k\to k-j\\=&\sum_{k=0}^{n}\sum_{j=0}^{n-k}a_kb_j&\text{Swap letters }k\text{ and }j\\=&\sum_{k=0}^{n}a_k\sum_{j=0}^{n-k}b_j&\text{Extract }a_k\text{ in front of the second sum}\end{array}$$

Answer (score 2):

A variation. We obtain
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\sum_{k=0}^n\sum_{j=0}^ka_jb_{k-j}}
&=\sum_{0\leq j\leq k\leq n}a_jb_{k-j}\tag{1}\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^n\sum_{k=j}^na_jb_{k-j}\tag{2}\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^n\sum_{k=0}^{n-j}a_jb_{k}\tag{3}\\
&\,\,\color{blue}{=\sum_{k=0}^n\sum_{j=0}^{n-k}a_kb_j}\tag{4}
\end{align*}
and the claim follows.

*Comment:*

- In (1) we write the index region conveniently to better see what's going on.
- In (2) we exchange the sums.
- In (3) we shift the index to start with $k=0$.
- In (2) we finally swap $k$ and $j$.

Answer (score 1):

You can display it expanding the sum $\sum\limits_{k=0}^n \sum\limits_{j=0}^k a_j b_{k-j}$  into a table. Start with each row being a different $k$ and each column a different $j$ to get

$$\begin{matrix}
a_0b_0  &+ &   & &  & &\\
a_0b_1  &+ &  a_1b_0 &+ &  & &\\ 
a_0b_2  &+ &  a_1b_1 &+ & a_2b_0 & +&\\
\cdots & &\cdots & &\cdots  & &  \ddots & \\
a_0b_{n-1}  &+ &  a_1b_{n-2}  &+ &  a_2b_{n-3}  &+& \cdots &+& a_{n-1}b_0&+\\
a_0b_n  &+ &  a_1b_{n-1}  &+ &  a_2b_{n-2}  &+& \cdots &+& a_{n-1}b_1 &+& a_nb_0\\
\end{matrix}$$

Then read the same expansion with each column being a separate $k$ and then for each $k$ the non-empty rows (so starting one lower each time) being a separate $j$ and you get $\sum\limits_{k=0}^n  a_k \sum\limits_{j=0}^{n-k} b_j$.